# Set position of a View from the centre instead of top left

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, android-view

I have a image view initialized in code. I am able to set the position via `setX()` and `setY()`. methods. As I understand, these coordinates are set to the top left corner of the image. However, I want to set the position according to the center of the image. Is this possible?

Note: I am new in Android development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot set the position according to the center.

But, you can calculate the position the top left corner should be, for the center to be in a specific x,y location, by subtracting half the width and height respectively.

You can call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get them.

So, you can do something like this:

```
fun setViewPositionAccordingToCenter(view: View, x: Int, y: Int){

    view.setX(x - (view.getWidth()/2))
    view.setY(y - (view.getHeight()/2))
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured I would have to calculate it. Thanks Tal.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue, to help other people find it in the future